# Sitecore Error : System.Net.WebException - The operation has timed out

Tags: sitecore-client, deployment, error-handling

After doing a deployment to the live server, I am getting this error in the logs multiple times due to which the website is not showing. This is the only error that is generated:

```
12136 23:10:30 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Sitecore.Common.Website.Pipelines.ExecuteRequestHandler.PerformRedirect(String url)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest.HandleItemNotFound(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I googled, but none of the issues resembled mine. I did an IISReset and app pool recycle.but still this error persists.
Any idea what could have caused this issue?

Comment: is there any extra logs around there? I had a similar issue and in my case, the issue was the keepalive page was not accessible by some hosting settings within the VM.
I think you should check if http(s)://<yourhostname/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx is accessible from the server where the sitecore instance is running.